# If standard Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud connector is setup in Sales Cloud, where are the data in Sales Cloud that correspond to MC Cloud views?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

marketing cloud connector salesforce where can we see data from _bounce _job _click _open _sent _subscribe _unsubscribe in sales cloud

If standard Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud connector is setup in Sales Cloud, where are the data in Sales Cloud that correspond to MC Cloud views `_bounce`, `_job`, `_click`, `_open`, `_sent`, `_subscribe`,  `_unsubscribe`?

If we are given `SQL` queries for extract jobs from MC Cloud, is this possible to translate them into `SOQL` queries for Sales Cloud?

We are building integration and we would prefer to connect to a single Sales Cloud to grab the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really possible with out-of-box configuration, since the data in those Data Views is available only in a very limited and restricted way in Sales Cloud objects.

You'll need to work with the custom objects (and their fields) created by the Marketing Cloud Connect managed package, which are: Individual Email Results, Aggregate Link Level Detail, Individual Link Level Detail, Email Linkage, Email Send, Mobile Send, Triggered Send.

From these objects you can identify most relevant fields and proceed to build SoQL queries and/or standard Salesforce reports.

An alternative approach could be to configure few custom objects in Sales Cloud and prepare an Automation from Marketing Cloud to feed these objects directly. This will allow you to keep a copy of Data Views in Sales Cloud, but keep in mind this solution will quickly eat up a lot of the (limited) storage space in your CRM, so plan ahead cautiously.